# Select query in same table name "master" need resultset if status = n, if status = N and status =P the result not display

Tags: mysql

**I have table name master_consmnt with below data**

```
fra_code    mode    cnum    cost    edate       status
ET7867FRA   SURFACE 19001   10.000  2014-01-17  P
ET7867FRA   SURFACE 19005   5.000   2014-01-17  P
ET7867FRA   SURFACE 19005   10.000  2014-01-17  P
FRANE3981   SURFACE 19005   0.000   2014-01-17  P
FRARE5664   SURFACE 19005   18.000  2014-01-17  N
FRARE5664   SURFACE 19001   14.000  2014-01-17  N
FRARE5664   SURFACE 180001  38.000  2014-01-17  N
```

I want cnum from table master_consmnt where cnum.status=N, please note in master table there is more than one cnum.status data

```
fra_code    mode    cnum    cost    edate       status
FRARE5664   SURFACE 180001  38.000  2014-01-17  N
```

The above is the actual result I needed, sorry for the question error posted previously.

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `master_consmnt`
WHERE NOT (

STATUS = "N"
AND STATUS = "P"
)
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: @AmitSoni: This is not going to happen.

Comment: Your result contradicts your logic.

Comment: please read the updated actual question

Answer (score 1):

As per your Posting title:

> *... need resultset if status = n, if status = N and status =P the result not display*

You may require case sensitive comparison.

```
select * from mast where binay(status)='n';
```

This query fetches all records that have `status` value as lower `n`.

But, your row data shows none have a `n` in `status` but a `N` or `P`.

Comment: this is the correct answer for the question:select mc.*
from master_consmnt mc
where mc.status = 'N' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from master_consmnt mc2
                  where mc2.cnum = mc.cnum and status = 'P'
                 );

Comment: @AmitSoni: Yes, I saw your other post with the same question. Here, you did not get proper responses because, you could not explain your requirement correctly. Your English was too bad in framing the sentences and explaining.

Answer (score 0):

### Gordon Linoff a stackoverflow member posted a currect answer to this question which is as follows

```
select mc.*
from master_consmnt mc
where mc.status = 'N' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from master_consmnt mc2
                  where mc2.cnum = mc.cnum and status = 'P'
                 );
```